# Solving Complicated Systems of Equation

Tags: equation-solving

If I have three equations as below:

$a_j = -(k+\sum_{i\neq j}^n\alpha_iba_i)^{-1}$, say $i,j=1,\cdots,n$.

I want to use Mathematica to solve this system of equations but I do not want to solve it completely for $a_1,\cdots,a_n$. I only want an equation of expression of $a_1$. For example, in the case of $n=2$, I have

$a_1=-(k+\alpha_1ba_2)^{-1}$ and
$a_2=-(k+\alpha_2ba_1)^{-1}$. Putting second equation into the first equation, I get $$a_1=-(k+\alpha_2 b(-k+\alpha_2ba_1)^{-1})^{-1}$$. I only need this expression but not to solve completely to get a value for $a_1$. Is there any way to do something like this for Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, it is hard in general. Can you please provide some background. Where these equations are coming from?

Comment: Please provide code for an example, in a form that can be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 5):

The first element of the [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) gives what you want; but it's rather hard to compute. According to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html),

> `GroebnerBasis[{poly1,poly2,…},{x1,x2,…},{y1,y2,…}]` finds a Gröbner basis in which the $y_i$ have been eliminated.

So we are looking for a polynomial in $a_1$ that has the same zeros as the given equations $a_j=eq(n,j)$ but where $a_2\ldots a_n$ have been eliminated:

```
eq[n_Integer, j_Integer] /; 1 <= j <= n :=
  -1/(k + Sum[Boole[i != j] α[i] b a[i], {i, n}])

sol1[n_Integer /; n >= 1] :=
  First@GroebnerBasis[Table[a[j] == eq[n, j], {j, n}],  (* equations          *)
                      {a[1]},                           (* keep this variable *)
                      Table[a[j], {j, 2, n}]]           (* eliminate these    *)

sol1[1] == 0
(*    1/k + a[1] == 0    *)

sol1[2] == 0
(*    k + k^2 a[1] + b a[1] α[1] + b k a[1]^2 α[1] - b a[1] α[2] == 0    *)

sol1[3] == 0
(*    -k^2 + k^4 a[1]^2 - 2 b k a[1] α[1] + 2 b k^2 a[1]^2 α[1] +
      4 b k^3 a[1]^3 α[1] - b^2 a[1]^2 α[1]^2 + 4 b^2 k a[1]^3 α[1]^2 +
      5 b^2 k^2 a[1]^4 α[1]^2 + 2 b^3 a[1]^4 α[1]^3 + 2 b^3 k a[1]^5 α[1]^3 -
      2 b k^2 a[1]^2 α[2] - 4 b^2 k a[1]^3 α[1] α[2] -
      2 b^3 a[1]^4 α[1]^2 α[2] + b^2 a[1]^2 α[2]^2 - 2 b k^2 a[1]^2 α[3] -
      4 b^2 k a[1]^3 α[1] α[3] - 2 b^3 a[1]^4 α[1]^2 α[3] -
      2 b^2 a[1]^2 α[2] α[3] + b^2 a[1]^2 α[3]^2 == 0    *)
```

For $n=4$ it's already taking too long.